# Controller parameter does not become null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I ran into the following problem:

I've got a asp.net mvc 5 controller with a reference type as a parameter:

```
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetFeeds(Location location)
    {
        if (location == null)
        {
            // init location or smth
        }

        // Do smth with location

        return new EmptyResult();
   }
```

You will notice that I'm using AttributeRouting. There are NO other methods with the name of this action.

However - this is my location class:

```
    public class Location : ILocation
    {
       public DbGeography Coordinates { get; set; }

       public double Latitude { get; set; }

       public double Longitude { get; set; }
    }
```

Nothing special here (the interface defines all of those properties).

If I'm accessing the controllers action (actually using powershell) and passing something like:

```
http://localhost:2000/Feed?latitude=23.1&longitude=37
```

everthing works fine but if I'm using

```
http://localhost:2000/Feed
```

the location parameter is NOT null (it is a new Location with default values), which is the behavior I want to have :( .

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The binder's working as designed - it's instantiating a `Location` object and populating its values with defaults except where you supply override values (which you aren't in the second example).  It won't create a null instance of your `Location` object just because your route supplied no values.

Comment: @ChristopherKellner - it does not appear possible due to "how the model binder" works.  Take a look at the link in my answer for a little bit more explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The MVC model binder has taken over.  What I originally posted would work in instances that do not go through the model binder.  However, [based on other answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634188/will-viewmodel-param-never-be-null-in-asp-net-mvc-3-action) and my own quick testing, it appears that a viewmodel parameter will never be null due to how the binder works and ties properties to form values.

In your instance, I would check if both latitude and longitude are null to see if nothing was passsed.  Which means you will need to make them nullable on your ViewModel

```
public class Location : ILocation
    {
       public DbGeography Coordinates { get; set; }

       public double? Latitude { get; set; }

       public double? Longitude { get; set; }
    }
```

Updated Controller Code

```
if (location.Latitude == null && location.Longitude == null)
    {
        // init location or smth
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but the location is still a new instance of Location. Any further suggestions?

Comment: @ChristopherKellner - yup, you are right, updated my answer for you

Comment: location.Latitude.HasValue will look nicer :D

Comment: It is very strange that it wouldn't map to null. What if you mark it as nullable? `(Location? location = null)`

Comment: @TravisJ  I could not make my test MVC app ever give me a null complex object, just a new instance of it with all properties null (or default values).  If you find a way, that would be awesome.  Also, marking it nullable made the compiler pissy, something about "Only non-nullable value types can be underlying System.Nullable"

Comment: @TravisJ i don't think it's strange, I think it's implemented that way by design.

Comment: @Bart - It would seem that the default model binder does instantiate by design.

Comment: It's a bad idea to put model-specific validation in a controller (controllers are hard to test and there's a high probability that you'll be repeating yourself).  ASP.Net MVC ships with data annotation validators for a very good reason.

Answer (score 4):

ModelBinder creates a new instance of the object, so you have two options here:

Have a `[Required]` DataAnnotation on 'required properties' AND mark them as nullable then check for `ModelState.IsValid` (recommended)

make Latitude and Longitude  nullable `double?` and you can check for `Latitude.HasValue && Longitude.HasValue`

**UPDATE :**

```
public class Location : ILocation
    {
       public DbGeography Coordinates { get; set; }

       public double? Latitude { get; set; }

       public double? Longitude { get; set; }
    }

public class LocationGetFeedsViewModel : LocationGetFeedsBinderModel {
       // change coordinates to string because maybe that's easier to handle on the view.
       public string Coordinates { get; set; }
       // added to sum to the example
       public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Zones { get; set; } 
}

public class LocationGetFeedsBinderModel {
       [Required]
       public double? Latitude { get; set; }
       [Required]
       public double? Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult GetFeeds(LocationGetFeedsBinderModel location) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        // redirect or display some error 
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: Sadly I'm not able to change those properties to nullable values since they are inherited by ILocation. I see 3 possibilities to achieve the goal: Creating a new VM class with nullable properties and parse them into a new Location or check both of them for 0 since this is very uncommon. Both feels wrong :/ The third would be nullable double as parameters which seems better. Or do yu have another idea?

Comment: That's what I call a `BinderModel` not ViewModel. This is extremelly usefull to have since viewModel normally got more properties than a form post that only accept 2 or 3. Best of both worlds. Actually I think it rare or even bad to have a controller to accept a full ViewModel.

Comment: So you would recommend the first approch using a "BinderModel"?

Comment: YES, YES and YES!. Definitely. In real word scenarios, when you have only 1 form, i do make the ViewModel inherits the BinderModel like : LocationEditViewModel : LocationEditBinderModel. You will have access to all properties on the view with the perfectly valid data annotations and the Post signature at the controller level will receive a LocationEditBinderModel. I do this for all POST. It's very important to me to have total control of how many properties are exposed and available for the user specially to avoid overposting at the model level and leaving the controller signature clean.

Comment: In your example, I can POST Coordinates property which i think it's not intended so you are exposing over-posting. this can be safe or bad as hell.. better to prevent it by design.

Answer (score 1):

The default model binder will always instantiate a complex object so it will unfortunately never be null and any optional assignment will be skipped.

The end result of this behavior as it applies to your system is going to be that you must detect the use of a default constructor. There is no way to do this with reflection or implicit inspection.

It must be done explicitly.

It could be accomplished by having a flag in the class set in the default constructor, with nullable properties as suggested in the accepted answer, by using data annotations as Bart suggests, by using custom get and set methods for the properties, or a variety of other ways.

Comment: This was my original answer.  The variable will still be non-null when you get into the ActionResult.  Tested myself on VS2013.  Guessing an update was made to the DefaultModelBinder at some point in MVC.

Comment: @Tommy - I removed the suggestion of using an optional property set to null. As you accurately state it will be instantiated and the optional value will never be assigned. Please see edits.

Answer (score 1):

I've been testing ***posting*** data with angularjs.

I find that if you force a value to **null** instead of **undefined**, ModelBinder doesn't instantiate a complex object.

```
if (!location)
    location = null;

$http({ method: "POST", url: "/Location/Create", data: { location } })
```

Comment: I am using React in 2020 and this worked perfectly.