# Why does MVC 5 create object with default constructor when specified as action parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an action that accepts a model as a parameter:

```
public ActionResult stuff (string a, string b, MyModel mod)
    {
        if (mod != null)
        {
            // perform action based on existing model values
        }
        else
        {
            // perform action based on no model (i.e. first time hitting the page)
        {
    }
```

If no model is passed then for some reason instead of `MyModel mod` being null .net creates an object with parameterless constructor so my `if` always evaluates to true.

Why does this happen? I'd rather this object doesn't have a parameterless constructor for simplicity as my constructors do a few processes that need certain values. I thought that in MVC 5 you could specify parameters and it would figure it out if they are left off.

The reason I have this logic is because page first loads up and creates the model there are lots of requests being made and I don't want these repeated every time user submits a change.

Is it best to create a property like:

```
public bool initialized { get; set; }
```

And then set it to true in all constructors apart from the default constructor?  Am I going about this whole thing the wrong way?

Comment: Is this a POST method?

Comment: How about getting a property value from mod, since it's not null. Then you can determine what action to take. Perhaps there is some null property value that you can check instead.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Right now its GET

Comment: @MikeG yeah this is what I have done but it just confuses me why it wants to create the object.  I feel like there is a proper approach for maintaining the state of the model I just do not know it as this doesn't feel right

Comment: Is this async call or postback?

Comment: @VenkataPanga Right now it is just what loads when View is first loaded, I have run into this issue before I have got to even posting back to the page

Comment: The process of model binding initializes an instance of the model. It has to do this because if you passed values for properties of that model, how would it set the model properties if it was `null`. Note your model need a parameterless constructor otherwise an exception will be thrown during the binding process.

Comment: The ViewModel will never be null, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634188/will-viewmodel-param-never-be-null-in-asp-net-mvc-3-action).  Usually you just check the ModelState to see if it's completely valid or contains errors

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov no, public class with public properties.

Comment: @Jonesy ahh, I didn't know about ModelState, this was what I needed thanks.  I will search on this.

Comment: I did realized that it can't be struct after posting comment since you mentioned having code in default constructor... I think your real option is use custom model binder if you need non-default behavior...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks, I will research custom binder.